# How can I disable the McCabe test MC0001 in Landscape.io?

Tags: python, code-complexity, landscape.io

[Landscape.io](https://landscape.io) offers nice and good Python code tests and based on [PEP 8](https://pep8.org/), [Pylint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pylint), [McCabe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity), etc.

Some of my parser methods contain big switch blocks, so I would like to disable the McCabe test MC0001 for selected methods. How can I do this?

I found this syntax for PyLint:

```
for file in get_files():  # pylint:disable=redefined-builtin
```

Source: https://docs.landscape.io/suppressing.html

... but no syntax is shown for `mccabe`. Based on my Google research, it's possible to disable a McCabe rule for all files in a project, but this is not my goal. Here is a YAML file globally disabling MC0001:

```
mccabe:
  disable:
  - MC0001
```

Source: <s>https://0x7df.wordpress.com/tag/mccabe/</s>

Comment: If you are using mccabe as a Flake8 plugin, you can disable it by the same means you disable Flake8 warnings: `# noqa: MC0001` on the respective line, see https://github.com/PyCQA/mccabe/tree/c2f5b386458cfda0aa4239f4d11b4e5e75027bda#plugin-for-flake8: "To silence violations reported by `mccabe`, place your `# noqa: C901` on the function definition line". Otherwise it's not possible (stated in the same section).

Comment: The link is broken: *"0x7df.wordpress.com is no longer available. The authors have deleted this site."*

Comment: The docs.landscape.io link is also broken: *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at docs.landscape.io."*

Comment: Firefox is not happy with the *landscape.io* link: *"Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead. Firefox detected a potential security threat and did not continue to landscape.io. If you visit this site, attackers could try to steal information like your passwords, emails, or credit card details."*

Comment: Landscape.io is a dead project. Please note, this question was asked 6 years ago ... The Internet is a living thing. Services come and go.